# Eliminar validación de un campo dependiendo del valor de otro campo

Tags: angular, typescript

Hola buenas tardes comunidad, vengo a ustedes porque tengo un detalle, tengo una función de editar datos el cual guardo los datos con sus respectivas validaciones, en esta función lo que tengo unos campos de tipo, empleado, nombre, apellido paterno y materno.

El problema que tengo es que cuando tipo el cual son dos valores diferentes (Internos y Externos) es interno, los campos, nombre y apellidos pueden estar vacíos y guardarse sin problema sin que salte la validación y cuando el campo tipo sea externo el campo empleado este vacío salte la alerta de q se requiere llenar ese campo y los otros de nombre y apellido no salte la alerta.

mi función es la siguiente:

```js
EditarDatosAsesor(){
    this.submit = true;
    
    if (this.FormularioAsesor.invalid) {
        //alert('llenar todos los campos')
        this.variablesFuncionesGlobalesService.variable_envio_formulario = false;
        return;
      } else {
        //alert('Datos insertados')
        try{
          let jsonFInal = {
            tipo: this.FormularioAsesor.value.tipo,
            id_colaborador: this.FormularioAsesor.value.empleado == '' ? null : this.FormularioAsesor.value.empleado,
            nombre: this.FormularioAsesor.value.nombre == '' ? null : this.FormularioAsesor.value.nombre,
            apellido_paterno: this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_paterno == '' ? null : this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_paterno,
            apellido_materno: this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_materno == '' ? null : this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_materno
          };
         //Api guardado de información
        } catch(e){
          console.log(e)
        }
      }
  }
```

Lo que estaba haciendo era poner una condicional siguiente, pero sería repetir muchas veces lo mismo, no sé si haya una mejor forma:

```js
EditarDatos(){
if(this.FormularioAsesor.value.tipo == 'I' ){      
        if (this.FormularioAsesor.invalid) {           this.variablesFuncionesGlobalesService.variable_envio_formulario = false;
            return;
          } else {
            try{
              let jsonFInal = {
                tipo: this.FormularioAsesor.value.tipo,
                id_colaborador: this.FormularioAsesor.value.empleado == '' ? null : this.FormularioAsesor.value.empleado,
                nombre: this.FormularioAsesor.value.nombre == '' ? null : this.FormularioAsesor.value.nombre,
                apellido_paterno: this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_paterno == '' ? null : this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_paterno,
                apellido_materno: this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_materno == '' ? null : this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_materno
              };
             //Api guardado de información
            } catch(e){
              console.log(e)
            }
          }
      } 
    } else {
    //Repetiria lo mismo lo que es mas codigo, 
    this.submit = true;
    
    }
}
```

En pocas palabras, lo que ando tratando de hacer es que cuando un empleado sea interno no salten las validaciones de nombre y apellidos, pero si salte la validación de empleado si llega estar vacío; y que cuando sea externo saltes las validaciones de nombre y apellidos si están vacíos y el de empleado no.

Answer (score 0):

podrías crear una validación a nivel de formulario completo en lugar de validaciones por cada campo.

Para ello podrías utilizar el servicio formBuilder para crear el formGroup.
En él como primer argumento pasas el objeto de los controles y en el segundo argumento puedes pasarle una validación

En la validación es donde desarrollas la lógica necesaria y asignarle error o no a cada campo (control) según tu necesidad

```
public FormularioAsesor= this.formBuilder.group(
{
  tipo: [''],
  nombre: [''],
  apellidos: [''],
  ....
  
},
{
  validators: this.validarCampos,
}
);

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {}

validarCampos(){
 return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
  const campo1 = formGroup.get('campoEvaluar')?.value;
  const campo2 = formGroup.get('campoEvaluar')?.value;

  if (lo que quieras evaluar) {
    formGroup.get('campoEvaluar')?.setErrors(null);
  } else {
    formGroup.get('campoEvaluar')?.setErrors({ campoNulo: true });
  }
}
```